# Rust in a plastic fermenter?

Tags: equipment, sanitation, troubleshooting, cleaning

I've got a 6 gallon plastic fermenter - one of those food-grade plastic buckets Midwest gives you in the starter kit. I guess after our last brew, my brother and I carelessly tossed the remains of our bag of bottlecaps in there without fully drying out the bucket. Brother just looked in there a few days ago and the caps are all rusty and there are some rust stains in the fermenter.

Obviously we can't use the caps now, but I'm more concerned about the fermenter. My gut tells me that if the stains do not come out with some water and a washrag they probably also won't come out into any beer we ferment in there, but I'm not sure. Should we just get another bucket just to be safe?

Comment: Have you tried getting the rust stains out yet? It should be possible, though you probably don't want anything too abrasive.

Comment: And by "probably," he means "definitely."  If you scratch that stuff, it gives bacteria a place to hide from your chemical sanitizer.  I've found magic erasers to be pretty good for getting stains out of these plastic buckets.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - my brother is in possession of the fermenter now and I'm not sure how much he has actually tried cleaning it yet. Hopefully the stains will just come out easily and it won't be an issue.

Comment: @DustinRasener: Would vinnegar work as well? I'd heard that the "magic erasers" contain some fairly toxic stuff, some apparently have formaldehyde in them. :(

Comment: @Frustrated: Snopes seems to think they're OK, but I know that we brewers often hold things to a higher standard. http://www.snopes.com/medical/toxins/eraser.asp

Comment: @frustrated - soaking in vinegar with some aluminum foil in it can remove iron oxide stains to some extent (redox reaction), but I personally wouldn't bother. Same trick is used to polish siver-plated objects without removing the silver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust stains are from the iron oxide that formed (this much I assume you know) from the iron in the caps. These stains will not harbor bacteria or other "nasties" to a significant level, as these are large organisms when compared to the iron oxide molecule.

Trying to remove them by scrubbing can indeed scratch the plastic, but there is no scientific evidence that these scratches provide breeding sites for bacteria, contrary to popular myth, **that can overcome the sanitizing action of iodine-based solutions** (the most common base for brewing sanitizers). Any additional bacteria will be killed when sanitizing is done properly, as the chemicals will enter the scratches themselves.

Personally, I'd ignore the stains that might remain after a good cleaning with oxyclean and subsequent sanitizing with I-O-Safe or iodine tablets and use the bucket without scrubbing to remove the stains.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't as much worried about bacteria as possible off tastes or other undesirable effects. I think you're probably right that anything that remains after a good cleaning is nothing to worry about though.

Comment: I can't speak to off-tastes, but I know that I have used both glass and approved plastic (certified not to impart flavors to contents, specifically made for purified water) carboys and have noticed no discernible difference in flavors over a couple of years use.

Comment: I think I can safely say that where people get into trouble is when they do not sanitize properly before starting the fermentation.

Comment: You specifically mention iodine-based solutions.  Can you speak to the efficacy of Star San with respect to scratches in plastic equipment?

Comment: I don't use StarSan, so I really can't. I do know that iodine-based sanitizers like I-O-Safe would easily kill any bacteria/yeast lodged in scratched in plastic. Most petri dishes used today are plastic and these are routinely sanitized in iodine solutions, when autoclaves are not available.

Comment: Just looked it up and Star San sanitizes as an acid, so it is using pH as the "killing action", and there are known pH-resistant strains of common bacteria. Iodine kills by oxidation/reduction of the molecules that make up the organisms. I would suspect the using Star San at the 300 ppm level that is suggested for non-rinse use is probably ok, But I haven't used it so I can't say from personal investigation.

Comment: Lots of folks brew in their kitchen and can't use iodine based solutions because they can't risk staining the counter-tops.  People with flow-through septic systems can't use it either.  One-step and Star San are what most brewers I know use.

Comment: Thanks, tin, didn't know that and it certainly makes sense. BTW - common household bleach can remove most of the iodine stain if you get to it quickly. Use gloves.

Comment: I have used Starsan to knock out infections that iodophor couldn't kill.

Comment: Thanks, Denny. Did you use the no-rinse concentration (300 ppm)?

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing a while back (actually a few times)

**Just use a sponge to get the rust marks off then sanitize like normal.**

I have brewed many batches since without ever getting sick.